# How to restart gerrit trigger automatically in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

everybody

Good day!

We are just using gerrit trigger in jenkins now. But sometimes we found it didn't work, and it turned out that the connection betweenn jenkins and gerrit server was down.

Always we were notified gerrit trigger didn't work and then restart the connection manually. It's really not a good way. We'd like to restart the connection automatically once the connection is down.

Does anyone has some good ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gerrit Trigger Plugin v. 2.14.0 or above, you can try to configure [Missed Events Playback Feature](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-MissedEventsPlaybackFeature%28Availablefromv.2.14.0%29). It needs additional Gerrit plugin as well.